# Why my child container is over lapping on main container

Tags: html, css

> Can anyone tell me how to solve this problem, As you can see my `.tab`
> class is set to 100% width and it's overlapping on the
> `.main-container` class? I also use overflow on my main container
> however it began having a scroll can any tell me what is the correct
> way to solve this problem? Thank you

```css
.main-container {
  border: 1px solid #D8D8D8;
  border-radius: 2px;
  width: 99%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  min-height: 10px;
  /*     overflow: auto; */
  margin-top: 3px;
  background: blue;
  padding: 10px;
}

.tabs {
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #f2f7fd;
  border-radius: 6px;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  color: #333333;
}

.tabs-title {
  margin-bottom: 6px;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #000000;
  line-height: 22px;
  padding: 0 2px;
}

.tabs-subtitle {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0 4px;
  line-height: 18px;
}

.tabs-subtitle+hr {
  height: 1px;
  border: none;
  background-color: #7a8a9a;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.tabs-content {
  position: relative;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -webkit-flex-direction: row;
  -ms-flex-direction: row;
  flex-direction: row;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.tabs-rdb {
  display: none;
  order: 1;
}

.tabs-lbl {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  padding: 8px 14px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: transparent;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 6px 6px 0 0;
  font-size: 13px;
  order: 2;
  font-weight: normal;
  user-select: none;
  color: #000000;
}

.tabs.tabs-lbl-bold .tabs-lbl {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.tabs-rdb+.tabs-lbl:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 1px;
  border: 6px;
  background-color: #2575c4;
  bottom: 2px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  transition: .32s ease width;
  opacity: 0;
}

.tabs.tabs-lbl-bold .tabs-rdb+.tabs-lbl:before {
  height: 2px;
}

.tabs-lbl:hover {
  color: #2575c4;
}

.tabs-lbl:first-of-type {
  margin-left: 16px;
}

.tabs-lbl:last-of-type {
  margin-right: 16px;
}

.tabs-rdb:checked+.tabs-lbl {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  color: #2575c4;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .14);
}

.tabs-rdb:checked+.tabs-lbl+.tabs-text {
  display: block;
}

.tabs-rdb:checked+.tabs-lbl:before {
  width: 32%;
  opacity: 1;
}

.tabs-text {
  display: none;
  top: 0;
  order: 999;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 6px;
  line-height: 18px;
  box-shadow: 0 0px 8px -4px rgba(0, 0, 0, .24);
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
  min-height: 38px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-container">
  <div class="tabs tabs-lbl-bold">
    <div class="tabs-title">Main Title (Optional)</div>
    <div class="tabs-subtitle">Subtitle Lorem ipsum dolor at met (Optional).</div>
    <hr>
    <div class="tabs-content">
      <input id="nkTabs_a_1" type="radio" class="tabs-rdb" checked name="tabs-a">
      <label for="nkTabs_a_1" class="tabs-lbl">Home</label>
      <div class="tabs-text">This area is for Home tab.</div>
      <!--  -->
      <input id="nkTabs_a_2" type="radio" class="tabs-rdb" name="tabs-a">
      <label for="nkTabs_a_2" class="tabs-lbl">About</label>
      <div class="tabs-text">
        This area is for About tab. This area is for About tab. This area is for About tab. This area is for About tab. This area is for About tab.
      </div>
      <!--  -->
      <input id="nkTabs_a_3" type="radio" class="tabs-rdb" name="tabs-a">
      <label for="nkTabs_a_3" class="tabs-lbl">Help</label>
      <div class="tabs-text">This area is for Help tab. This area is for Help tab.</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This overflow is caused by the box-sizing. Just add `.tabs { box-sizing: border-box; }` and the issue should be fixed.

The default value of `box-sizing: content-box` does not include the paddings and border. As such 100% width of the parent + paddings and border will always overflow! As such you have an overflow by 22px without `border-box`

PS: To stop the horizontal overflow of the viewport you should use `width: auto` instead of `width: 99%` on the wrapping parent element.

```css
.tabs {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* original CSS */
.main-container {
  border: 1px solid #D8D8D8;
  border-radius: 2px;
  width: 99%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  min-height: 10px;
  /*     overflow: auto; */
  margin-top: 3px;
  background: blue;
  padding: 10px;
}

.tabs {
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #f2f7fd;
  border-radius: 6px;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  color: #333333;
}

.tabs-title {
  margin-bottom: 6px;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #000000;
  line-height: 22px;
  padding: 0 2px;
}

.tabs-subtitle {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0 4px;
  line-height: 18px;
}

.tabs-subtitle+hr {
  height: 1px;
  border: none;
  background-color: #7a8a9a;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.tabs-content {
  position: relative;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -webkit-flex-direction: row;
  -ms-flex-direction: row;
  flex-direction: row;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.tabs-rdb {
  display: none;
  order: 1;
}

.tabs-lbl {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  padding: 8px 14px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: transparent;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 6px 6px 0 0;
  font-size: 13px;
  order: 2;
  font-weight: normal;
  user-select: none;
  color: #000000;
}

.tabs.tabs-lbl-bold .tabs-lbl {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.tabs-rdb+.tabs-lbl:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 1px;
  border: 6px;
  background-color: #2575c4;
  bottom: 2px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  transition: .32s ease width;
  opacity: 0;
}

.tabs.tabs-lbl-bold .tabs-rdb+.tabs-lbl:before {
  height: 2px;
}

.tabs-lbl:hover {
  color: #2575c4;
}

.tabs-lbl:first-of-type {
  margin-left: 16px;
}

.tabs-lbl:last-of-type {
  margin-right: 16px;
}

.tabs-rdb:checked+.tabs-lbl {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  color: #2575c4;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .14);
}

.tabs-rdb:checked+.tabs-lbl+.tabs-text {
  display: block;
}

.tabs-rdb:checked+.tabs-lbl:before {
  width: 32%;
  opacity: 1;
}

.tabs-text {
  display: none;
  top: 0;
  order: 999;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 6px;
  line-height: 18px;
  box-shadow: 0 0px 8px -4px rgba(0, 0, 0, .24);
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
  min-height: 38px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-container">
  <div class="tabs tabs-lbl-bold">
    <div class="tabs-title">Main Title (Optional)</div>
    <div class="tabs-subtitle">Subtitle Lorem ipsum dolor at met (Optional).</div>
    <hr>
    <div class="tabs-content">
      <input id="nkTabs_a_1" type="radio" class="tabs-rdb" checked name="tabs-a">
      <label for="nkTabs_a_1" class="tabs-lbl">Home</label>
      <div class="tabs-text">This area is for Home tab.</div>
      <!--  -->
      <input id="nkTabs_a_2" type="radio" class="tabs-rdb" name="tabs-a">
      <label for="nkTabs_a_2" class="tabs-lbl">About</label>
      <div class="tabs-text">
        This area is for About tab. This area is for About tab. This area is for About tab. This area is for About tab. This area is for About tab.
      </div>
      <!--  -->
      <input id="nkTabs_a_3" type="radio" class="tabs-rdb" name="tabs-a">
      <label for="nkTabs_a_3" class="tabs-lbl">Help</label>
      <div class="tabs-text">This area is for Help tab. This area is for Help tab.</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```